# Invertible Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $S,T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that if $ST$ is invertible, then both $S$ and $T$ are invertible.

This is the partial question retrieved from Linear Algebra Done Right, and I have come out with different solution from the solution guide.

My solution: 
Since $ST$ is invertible, then the only possibility for $(ST)u=0$ is when $u=0$. Therefore I have $(ST)(0)=0=S(T(0))=0$. Since $T(0)=0$ (as proven in book), I must have $S(0)=0$. Since $T(0)=0$ and $S(0)=0$ comes directly from $(ST)(0)=0$, both $S$ and $T$ are injective. Since both of them are linear operator, we can deduce they are both invertible (by equivalece statement.)

Is my proof valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For *any* linear map $f$ it is true that $f(0)=0$. Therefore, nothing can be deduced from the fact that that happens for a specific linear map.

Comment: Yes I know. But the condition have been restricted to $(ST)u=0$ is only true when $u=0$, this also mean the only possible value for $Tu=0$ is when $u=0$ or else the former statement will be wrong isn't?

Comment: Not entirely, since if we do not know in advance that $S$ is injective then $Tu$ might be non-zero and then $Tu$ may be sent by $S$ to zero. So we need injectivity of $S$.

Comment: @LingMinHao Just to be sure: I was about to write the same thing that Radek Suchánek wrote.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $Tu$ can't be non-zero because $u$ must be zero from this case (due to the fact that $ST$ is invertible and hence injective ) . Since $u$ must be zero, then $Tu=T(0)$ must be zero isn't?

Comment: @LingMinHao I answered to what you wrote in your question. I agree with your first two sentences after “My solution”. But then you wrote: “ Since T(0)=0 […] I must have $S(0)=0$”. But you **always** have $S(0)=0$, because you are assuming that $S$ is linear. If you were aiming at proving that $S$ is injective, what you should prove was that $u\neq0\implies T(u)\neq0$ not that $u=0\implies T(u)=0$.

Comment: I think i got your point there. Instead of writing "Since $T(0)=0$, I must have $S(0)=0$. ", I should write "The only possible case for  $S(T(u))=0$ is when $T(u)=0$ where $T(u)=0$ follows immediately from $u=0$ since $(ST)u=0$ is only true when $u=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As José Carlos Santos stated, your proof is not correct. You have to show two things: injectivity and surjectivity of both $S$ and $T$. If you want to use zero element in your proof then injectivity can be shown by proving the following implication $$ f(u) = 0 \Rightarrow u = 0 \ ,$$ 
that is, you do not assume in the beginning that $u$ is zero.

Other hint that might be useful in the proof: If $ST$ is injective then $T$ must be injective. If $ST$ is surjective then $S$ must be surjective.

Comment: I do not have to prove both injectivity and surjectivity as $S$ and $T$ are both operator. Ya you are right if $ST$ is injective then $T$ must be injective. From here, I know the only possibility for $Tu=0$ is when $u=0$ ( because from injectivity , it must be one to one.), SInce $T(0)=0$, then we also have $S(T(u))=0$ $\Rightarrow S(T(0))=0$ $\Rightarrow S(0) = 0$.

Comment: To further clarify, I didn't assume $u=0$. It's from the fact that $ST$ is invertible implies that $u$ can only be 0 in order for $(ST)u=0$

Comment: Note:" $T$ is injective if and only if null $T$={0}." This is the theorem why I said the only possible values for $u$ is zero if a linear map is injective and $Tu=0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that since ST is invertible

$$\forall u\neq 0\iff (ST)u\neq0$$

then since

$$(ST)u=(S)((T)u)\neq0 \implies v=(T)u\neq0$$

thus T is invertible.

Since T is surjective, we have that $\forall v\neq0 \quad\exists u\neq0 \quad v=(T)u$ and $S(v) \neq 0$, therefore also S is invertible.